# String copy and paste

Tags: python

I have a string like this `1:sometext:othertext` and I have to copy the part after the second colon and paste it at the end of it, `1:sometext:othertext othertext`

can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show what you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
str1 = "hello:hi:world"
x, y, str2 = str1.split(":")
str1 = str1 + str2 # if you need space then str1 = str1+" "+str2
print(str1)
```

Comment: actually i have 400000+ lines of this, so i need to automate this. How can that be done?

Comment: You are reading it from file ? or you just have those lines in your script ?

Comment: @Deepak: Just iterate over the data. If you don't know what I'm talking about please reread the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use string built in `split` function to do this.

```
text = '1:sometext:othertext'
text + ' ' + text.split(':')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = """1:some text:othertext
2:sometext:othertext
3:sometext:othertext"""

lines = lines.split('\n')

for line in lines:
    key, some, other = line.split(':')
    print '%s  %s' % [line, other]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce output as required

```
text = '1:sometext:othertext'

text = " ".join(text.split(":")[2:])
```

'1:sometext:othertext'  -->  othertext

'1:sometext:othertext:abc:jkl'  -->  othertext abc jkl